# Php select default dropdown based on dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, dynamic

Building an edit users form for my system and having a little trouble trying to figure out how to do a  **selected="selected"** for the value in the dropdown that goes with the users information in the database.

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/EVdUfTzN

The names of the offices are stored in one table called **offices** and the value of the office that the patient went to is stored in **patients**. Basically I want to select the information from both tables and add a selected option on it.

Here is picture of the **offices** table
[image]

Here is a picture of the **patients** table
[image]

Do you understand what i am trying to do? Maybe even simplify it so its one query with INNER JOIN

Comment: you want to be auto selected the one that is stored in db?

Comment: Yes exactly, Im having trouble where to do that.

Comment: $row['office_id'] is $row['pat_loc']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (replace lines 25-29):

```
<?php
while ($dd_loc_row = mysql_fetch_array($dd_loc_result)) {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $dd_loc_row['office_id'] . "\"".($row['pat_loc'] == $dd_loc_row['office_id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '').">" . $dd_loc_row["office_name"] . "</option>";
}
?>
```